# Empty action bar in "MainActivity2" Android Studio

Tags: android, android-activity, action

I have created with Android Studio 1.4 a Blank Activity where I can set menu's items to diplay. 
My problem is that when I create a new activity "MainActivity2" I see the Action Bar with its colours but I'm not able to "connect" a menu with its elements. By default "onOptionsItemSelected" and "onCreateOptionsMenu" are not created automatically in this new activity.
Thanks

[First activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiR2x.png), 
[MainActivity2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCGiU.png)

Comment: So what's your problem? Why don't you see how it's done in the first activity and do something similar in the second?

Comment: Hi, I tried to copy all the code in the new activity but there's no way to male items to appear in the bar. I tried to create another menu.xml but it works only in the main activity. I tried to add in "OnCreateMenu" inflate menu.xml but nothing appears :/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I saw some tutorials in Internet saying that to change activity I have to use "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)". By the way using this the application will override only the design and will never be executed the "onCreateOptionsMenu" where menu items are going to be added. The correct action to execute on the button listener is " startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class)) ", so that the code can be executed.